# How do I independently move the pads of the ping pong for 2 players?

Tags: java, processing

so I just started doing some java with processing and encounter the problem that I can't move the pads independently from one another.

While I move pad1 and start pad2, pad1 just stops and the other way around, so that the two players interfere each others actions when the game gets faster.

I tried to reach a difference by turning the pads into objects, but I didn't accomplish any changes to the problem itself. the end for the code can be ignored for now cause I think I will fix this with a forLoop.

```
float player_1_x;
float player_1_y;
float player_2_x;
float player_2_y;
float ball_x;
float ball_y;
float ball_vector_x;
float ball_vector_y;

int round;

void setup() {
  player_1_x = 20;
  player_1_y = 60;
  player_2_x = 780;
  player_2_y = 60;
  ball_x = 400;
  ball_y = 300;
  ball_vector_x = -3;
  ball_vector_y = 0;
  round = 0;
  size(800, 600);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  rect(ball_x, ball_y, 10, 10);
  rect(player_2_x, player_2_y, 20, 100);
  if(keyPressed) {
    if(keyCode == DOWN && player_2_y < 550) {
      player_2_y += 5;
      }
    if(keyCode == UP && player_2_y > 50) {
      player_2_y -= 5;
      }
  }
  rect(player_1_x, player_1_y, 20, 100);
  if(keyPressed) {
    if(key == 's' && player_1_y < 550) {
      player_1_y += 5;
      }
    if(key == 'w' && player_1_y > 50) {
      player_1_y -= 5;
      }
  }
  ball_x += ball_vector_x;
  ball_y += ball_vector_y;
  if(ball_x < 30) {
    if(ball_y < (player_1_y + 55) && ball_y > (player_1_y - 55)) {
      ball_vector_x = (-ball_vector_x) + 0.5;
      ball_vector_y -= (player_1_y - ball_y) * 0.05;
    } else {
        ball_x = 400;
        ball_y = 300;
        ball_vector_x = -3;
        ball_vector_y = 0;
        round = 0;
    }
  }
  if(ball_x > 770) {
    if(ball_y < (player_2_y +55) && ball_y > (player_2_y - 55)) {
      ball_vector_x = (-ball_vector_x) - 0.5;
      ball_vector_y -= (player_2_y - ball_y) * 0.05;
    } else {
        ball_x = 400;
        ball_y = 300;
        ball_vector_x = 3;
        ball_vector_y = 0;
        round = 0;
    }
  }
  if(ball_y > 595 || ball_y < 5) {
    ball_vector_y = -ball_vector_y;
  }
  if(ball_vector_x == 4 || ball_vector_x == -4) {
    round = 1;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 5 || ball_vector_x == -5) {
    round = 2;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 6 || ball_vector_x == -6) {
    round = 3;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 7 || ball_vector_x == -7) {
    round = 4;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 8 || ball_vector_x == -8) {
    round = 5;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 9 || ball_vector_x == -9) {
    round = 6;
  } else if(ball_vector_x == 10 || ball_vector_x == -10) {
    round = 7;
  }
  text("round: " + round, 380, 20);

}
```

Comment: I think we need to see the code that shows where `key`, `keyCode` and `keyPressed` (and any others) come from

Comment: @SteveSmith These are built in to the Processing language.

Comment: Can Processing provide you with information about multiple concurrent key presses?  And what is the difference between `key` and `keyCode`?

Comment: @SteveSmith **key** is an actual key on the keyboard as you spell it like a char or a number and **keyCode** defines keys like the arrow keys, return and space

Comment: Shameless self promotion: [User Input in Processing](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). See the "handling multiple key presses" section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept multiple inputs at once without collision, use the `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` functions. No matter when you press a key, these functions will accept your input. However, these only register when you press and release a key, and not when you are holding down a key. To correct for this, make boolean variables for up and down, and when they are true, move the paddles. This allows you to move the paddles smoothly and at any time, without any issues or interference. You can then remove the if-statements that check for the keys in the `draw()` loop. In practice, it looks like this:

```
boolean player_1_down;//Initialize all of these to false in setup.
boolean player_1_up;
boolean player_2_down;
boolean player_2_up ;

....


void keyPressed(){
   if(key == 's') {
      player_1_down = true;
   }
   if(key == 'w' ) {
     player_1_up = true;
   }
   if(keyCode == DOWN ) {
      player_2_down = true;
   }
   if(keyCode == UP ) {
      player_2_up = true;
   }
}

void keyReleased(){
   if(key == 's' ) {
      player_1_down = false;
   }
   if(key == 'w') {
     player_1_up = false;
   }
   if(keyCode == DOWN ) {
      player_2_down = false;
   }
   if(keyCode == UP) {
      player_2_up = false;
   }
}
```

Then, in your `draw()` loop, near the top, put this, to make your paddles move:

```
if(player_1_down && player_1_y < 550){
    player_1_y += 5;
}else if(player_1_up && player_1_y > 50){
    player_1_y -= 5;
}
if(player_2_down && player_2_y < 550){
    player_2_y += 5;
}else if(player_2_up&& player_2_y > 50){
    player_2_y -= 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work from what i expected. now i can control them simultaneously.